# How to create Multi-Level Treeview in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview

I have implemented a code to create Tree View and also save it into database.

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult IndexMda()
    {
        using (BackendEntities context = new BackendEntities())
        {
            var plist = context.MDA.Where(p => p.PARENT_MDA_ID == null).Select(a => new
            {
                a.MDA_ID,
                a.MDA_NAME,
                a.MDA_DESCRIPTION,
                a.ORGANIZATION_TYPE
            }).ToList();
            ViewBag.plist = plist;
        }
        GetHierarchy();
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult GetHierarchy()
    {
        List<MDA2> hdList;
        List<MdaViewModel> records;
        using (BackendEntities context = new BackendEntities())
        {
            hdList = context.MDA.ToList();

            records = hdList.Where(l => l.PARENT_MDA_ID == null)
                .Select(l => new MdaViewModel
                {
                    MDA_ID = l.MDA_ID,
                    text = l.MDA_NAME,
                    MDA_DESCRIPTION = l.MDA_DESCRIPTION,
                    ORGANIZATION_TYPE = l.ORGANIZATION_TYPE,
                    PARENT_MDA_ID = l.PARENT_MDA_ID,
                    children = GetChildren(hdList, l.MDA_ID)
                }).ToList();
        }

        return this.Json(records, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        // return View();
    }

    private List<MdaViewModel> GetChildren(List<MDA2> hdList, long PARENT_MDA_ID)
    {
        return hdList.Where(l => l.PARENT_MDA_ID == PARENT_MDA_ID)
            .Select(l => new MdaViewModel
            {
                MDA_ID = l.MDA_ID,
                text = l.MDA_NAME,
                MDA_DESCRIPTION = l.MDA_DESCRIPTION,
                ORGANIZATION_TYPE = l.ORGANIZATION_TYPE,
                PARENT_MDA_ID = l.PARENT_MDA_ID,
                children = GetChildren(hdList, l.MDA_ID)
            }).ToList();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChangeNodePosition(long MDA_ID, long PARENT_MDA_ID)
    {
        using (BackendEntities context = new BackendEntities())
        {
            var Hd = context.MDA.First(l => l.MDA_ID == MDA_ID);
            Hd.PARENT_MDA_ID = PARENT_MDA_ID;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return this.Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddNewNode(AddNode model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (BackendEntities db = new BackendEntities())
                {
                    MDA2 hierarchyDetail = new MDA2()
                    {
                        MDA_NAME = model.NodeName,
                        PARENT_MDA_ID = model.ParentName,
                        MDA_DESCRIPTION = model.NodeDescription,
                        ORGANIZATION_TYPE = model.NodeOrganizationType
                    };

                    db.MDA.Add(hierarchyDetail);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The partial view is where the Tree View is created
**Partial View**

```
@model BPP.CCSP.Admin.Web.ViewModels.AddNode

<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Node</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewNode", "Mda", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formaddNode", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="col-md-6 row">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Perent Node" readonly="readonly">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.NodeTypeRbtn, "Pn", new { @class = "btn btn-primary  rbtnnodetype" })
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group ">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Child Node" readonly="readonly">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.NodeTypeRbtn, "Cn", new { @class = "rbtnnodetype" })
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NodeTypeRbtn, "", new { @class = "alert-error" })
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="petenddiv hidden">
                    @Html.Label("Select Parent")
                    @Html.DropDownList("ParentName", new SelectList(ViewBag.plist, "MDA_ID", "MDA_NAME"), "--select--", new { @class = "form-control" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ParentName, "", new { @class = "alert-error" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div>
                    @Html.Label("MDA Name")
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NodeName, new { @class = "form-control" })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NodeName, "", new { @class = "alert-error" })
                </div>

            </div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Description")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NodeDescription, new { @class = "form-control" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NodeDescription, "", new { @class = "alert-error" })
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Organization Type")

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NodeOrganizationType, new List<SelectListItem>
                                    {
                                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Agency", Value = "Agency"},
                                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Commission", Value = "Commission"},
                                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Department", Value = "Department"},
                                        new SelectListItem{Text = "Ministry", Value = "Ministry"}
                                    }, "Select Error Type", new { @style = "border-radius:3px;", @type = "text", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Organization Type", @autocomplete = "on" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NodeDescription, "", new { @class = "alert-error" })
    </div>

</div>

            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <input type="submit" id="savenode" value="S A V E" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <input type="button" id="closePopOver" value="C L O S E" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>


        }

    </div>
</div>
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin:100px auto;">
<div class="modal fade in" id="modalAddNode" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    @Html.Partial("_AddNode")
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Ministries, Departments and Agencies -: [ Add MDA and its Members ]</div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="tree"></div>

            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>

            <br />
            <div>
                <button id="btnDeleteNode" data-toggle="modal" class='btn btn-danger'> Delete Node <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button>
                <button id="btnpopoverAddNode" data-toggle="modal" class='btn btn-warning'> Add Node <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Scipts**

```js
@section Scripts {
    @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/conditional-validation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Gijgo/gijgo.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.gijgo.com/1.3.0/css/gijgo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //'Hierarchy/GetHierarchy'
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var Usertree = "";
            var tree = "";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: '/Mda/GetHierarchy',
                success: function (records, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    tree = $('#tree').tree({
                        primaryKey: 'MDA_ID',
                        dataSource: records,
                        dragAndDrop: true,
                        checkboxes: true,
                        iconsLibrary: 'glyphicons',
                        //uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
                    });
                    Usertree = $('#Usertree').tree({
                        primaryKey: 'MDA_ID',
                        dataSource: records,
                        dragAndDrop: false,
                        checkboxes: true,
                        iconsLibrary: 'glyphicons',
                        //uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
                    });

                    tree.on('nodeDrop', function (e, MDA_ID, PARENT_MDA_ID) {
                        currentNode = MDA_ID ? tree.getDataById(MDA_ID) : {};
                        console.log("current Node = " + currentNode);
                        parentNode = PerentId ? tree.getDataById(PARENT_MDA_ID) : {};
                        console.log("parent Node = " + parentNode);

                        if (currentNode.PARENT_MDA_ID === null && parentNode.PARENT_MDA_ID === null) {
                            alert("Parent node is not droppable..!!");
                            return false;
                        }
                        // console.log(parent.HierarchyLevel);
                        var params = { MDA_ID: MDA_ID, PARENT_MDA_ID: PARENT_MDA_ID };
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Mda/ChangeNodePosition",
                            data: params,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "Get",
                                    url: "/Mda/GetHierarchy",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function (records) {
                                        Usertree.destroy();
                                        Usertree = $('#Usertree').tree({
                                            primaryKey: 'MDA_ID',
                                            dataSource: records,
                                            dragAndDrop: false,
                                            checkboxes: true,
                                            iconsLibrary: 'glyphicons',
                                            //uiLibrary: 'bootstrap'
                                        });
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });

                    });

                    $('#btnGetValue').click(function (e) {
                        var result = Usertree.getCheckedNodes();
                        if (result == "") { alert("Please Select Node..!!") }
                        else {
                            alert("Selected Node id is= " + result.join());
                        }
                    });
                       //delete node
                    $('#btnDeleteNode').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var result = tree.getCheckedNodes();
                        if (result != "") {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/Mda/DeleteNode",
                                data: { values: result.toString() },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("Deleted successfully ");
                                    window.location.reload();
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
                                },
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Please select Node to delete..!!");
                        }


                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });

            // show model popup to add new node in Tree
            $('#btnpopoverAddNode').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#modalAddNode").modal("show");
            });

            //Save data from PopUp
            $(document).on("click", "#savenode", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#formaddNode'));
                $('#formaddNode').validate();
                if ($('#formaddNode').valid()) {
                    var formdata = $('#formaddNode').serialize();
                    // alert(formdata);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Mda/AddNewNode",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: formdata,
                        success: function (response) {
                            // $("#modalAddNode").modal("hide");
                            window.location.reload();
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert('Exception found');
                            //  $("#modalAddNode").modal("hide");
                            window.location.reload();
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            //  $('.ajax-loader').css("visibility", "hidden");
                        }
                    });
                }

            });

            //Close PopUp
            $(document).on("click", "#closePopup", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#modalAddNode").modal("hide");
            });

            $('.rbtnnodetype').click(function (e) {
                if ($(this).val() == "Pn") {
                    $('.petenddiv').attr("class", "petenddiv hidden");

                    $("#ParentName").val("");
                }
                else {
                    $('.petenddiv').attr("class", "petenddiv");
                }
            });

        });

    </script>

}
```

[image: Treeview]

As shown above, what I have created can only do one level node. I want want to create multi-level.Whereby, a child will be a parent to other children.

Please how do I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can see some ASP.NET examples about this at https://github.com/atatanasov/gijgo-asp-net-examples/tree/master/Gijgo.Asp.NET.Examples
Please use our examples in order to achieve that.